# Get parameters from Rest Http url for get method using streamsets microservice pipeline

Tags: web-services, microservices, kudu, streamsets

I have created a microservice pipeline in streamsets. Upon making a get callout, i have to retrieve data from mysql depending on the parameters sent in the http get url using expression evaluator?

My url is supposed to be like this: `http://my.url.com:0191?param1=xyz&param2=abc`

I have to retrieve data based on `param1` value and `param2` value.

Also, how do I handle cases when the params send will be null?

Answer (score 0):

The URL parameters appear in the `queryString` record header attribute; you can parse them out in an [Expression Evaluator](https://streamsets.com/documentation/datacollector/latest/help/datacollector/UserGuide/Processors/Expression.html#concept_zm2_pp3_wq) with the Field Expression:

```
${str:splitKV(record:attribute('queryString'), '&', '=')}
```

If you set the Output Field to `/`, then your parameters will now be in the fields `/param1` and `/param2`. You can use these in a MySQL query in the [JDBC Lookup](https://streamsets.com/documentation/datacollector/latest/help/datacollector/UserGuide/Processors/JDBCLookup.html#concept_ysc_ccy_hw) processor like this:

```
-- Assuming col1 is an integer (doesn't need quotes) and col2 is a string (needs quotes)
SELECT * FROM tablename 
WHERE col1 = ${record:value('/param1') AND col2 = '${record:value('/param2')'
```

You can handle nulls using the `record:attributeOrDefault()` function to set a default, or by using a [Stream Selector](https://streamsets.com/documentation/datacollector/latest/help/datacollector/UserGuide/Processors/StreamSelector.html#concept_tqv_t5r_wq) to send the record along a different path.